# Checking if two char array elements are the same c

Tags: c, arrays, char, compare

I've got some code in my program that essentially does this

```
char array[3] = {'g', 'w', 'a'};
char array2[3] = {'h', 'o', 'd'};
int i; 
int b = 1;
for (i = 0; i<=2; i++){
    if (array[i] != array2[i]){
        b = 0;
    }
}
if (b == 1){
    printf("true");
}
else{
    printf("false");
}
```

}

When I run it it outputs true no matter what values are in the arrays, even if they are completely different. Why aren't they being compared properly?

Here's the actual code because people can't seem to reproduce my error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int compare(char word1[], char word2[]){
    int i, k, same = 1, j, a, b;

    for (i =0; i<=79; i++){
        for (k=i; k <= 79; k++){
            if (word1[i] > word1[k]){
                char temp = word1[i];
                word1[i] = word1[k];
                word1[k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }


    for (a =0; a<=79; a++){
        for (b=a; b <= 79; b++){
            if (word2[a] > word2[b]){
                char temp = word2[a];
                word2[a] = word2[b];
                word2[b] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (j =0; j <= 79; j++){
        putchar(word1[j]);
        putchar(word2[j]);
        putchar('\n');
        if (word1[j] != word2[j]){
            same = 0;
        }
    }
    if (same = 1){
        printf("Anagrams");
    }
    else{
        printf("Not Anagrams");
    }
}

int split(char array[]){
    int a, b, c, second = 0, count = 0;
    char word2[80] = "", word1[80] ="";
    for(a=0; a <= 79; a++){
        if (array[a] != 0){
            if (array[a] == ' '){
                second = 1;
                count = 0;
            }
            else{  //add to array
                if (second == 0){
                    word1[count] = array[a];
                    count ++;
                }
                else{
                    word2[count] = array[a];
                    count ++;
                }
            } 
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    compare(word1, word2);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    char temp, words[80] = "";
    int count = 0;
    while ((temp=getchar()) != EOF){
        if (temp == '\n'){
            split(words);
            memset(words, 0, 80);
            count = 0;
        }
        else{
            words[count] = temp;
            count ++;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0){
        split(words);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you actually ran?

Comment: The posted  code looks OK to me. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The code is fine until and unless he use arrays as string .

Comment: No, this is the readers digest version of the code. The actual code is similar, except the characters are added into the array using getchar, and the arrays are longer. I know for a fact that these values ARE different in the arrays.

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](http://ideone.com/3UDgdk)

Comment: @Jay We need to see code that reproduces the problem otherwise there's no point asking. The code you've shown us looks right.

Comment: @Jay My suspicion is that you're somehow comparing an array with itself.

Comment: @Paul Nice hyoothesis...could be right

Comment: I added my full program, I know it's kind of sketchy because I'm not using dynamically sized arrays.

Comment: Best way to compare two char arrays is to create array lookup table.

Comment: Recent OP edit made post/answer inconsistent with answers and accepted solution.  Reverted to previous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the problem is here:

```
if (same = 1){
```

That should have been

```
if (same == 1){
```

Using `-Wall` in gcc reveals the problem quickly.

```
cc -Wall -std=c99     soc.c   -o soc
soc.c: In function ‘compare’:
soc.c:35:5: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
     if (same = 1){
```

Comment: Wow I am the dumbest guy ever. That solved it, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jay, don't feel bad. You are not the first to make that mistake and certainly won't be the last.

Comment: @Jay: people say that C is a risky language that lets you make these kinds of errors, but no one who uses C seriously compiles without -Wall (and probably even -Werror), you will do well to use them, especially if you are learning.

Answer (score 3):

logic error, replace `if(same = 1)` to `if(same)`.

Comment: @immibis Correct, but a lot of matured 'c' programmers tend to use `if(same)` just because you don't care what value `same' holds, as long as its not 0...